# Node.js HTTP2 server Error: socket hang up

Tags: node.js, http, https, server, http2

Given the latest version of Node.js with experimental HTTP2 support:

```
$ node -v
v9.2.0
```

An HTTP2 server:

```
var options = {
  key: getKey(),
  cert: getCert(),
  allowHTTP1: true
}

var server = http2.createSecureServer(options)
server.on('stream', onstream)
server.on('error', onerror)
server.on('connect', onconnect)
server.on('socketError', onsocketerror)
server.on('frameError', onframeerror)
server.on('remoteSettings', onremotesettings)
server.listen(8443)

function onconnect() {
  console.log('connect')
}

function onremotesettings(settings) {
  console.log('remote settings', settings)
}

function onframeerror(error) {
  console.log('frame error', error)
}

function onsocketerror(error) {
  console.log('socket error', error)
}

function onerror(error) {
  console.log(error)
}

function onstream(stream, headers) {
  console.log('stream')
}
```

And a request made to it:

```
var https = require('https')

var options = {
  method: 'GET',
  hostname: 'localhost',
  port: '8443',
  path: '/',
  protocol: 'https:',
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
  agent: false
}

var req = https.request(options, function(res){
  var body = ''
  res.setEncoding('utf8')
  res.on('data', function(data){
    body += data;
  });
  res.on('end', function(){
    callback(null, body)
  })
})

req.end()
```

It just hangs and eventually says:

```
Error: socket hang up
at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:330:15)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:423:23)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:164:20)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1054:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

If `rejectUnauthorized: true` is set, then it errors:

```
Error: self signed certificate
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1036:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:159:13)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:637:8)
```

Not sure what is going wrong and why it won't get to the point of logging `stream`.

If I go in the browser and visit https://localhost:8443, and click through the warning messages, it does actually log `stream` and successfully make the request. But haven't been able to get node to make the request.

I would like to treat this as an HTTP1 server, so don't want to use the HTTP2 client to make the request. But tried using that and same thing.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47585757/openssl-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47612763/node-js-rejecting-certificate-but-the-browser-accepts-it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

HTTP/1 doesn't share the same request semantics as HTTP/2 so HTTP/1 clients need to be detected and handled in a HTTP/2 server. To support both you need to use the [HTTP2 Compatibility API](https://nodejs.org/api/http2.html#http2_compatibility_api).

The "hang" occurs when a HTTP1 client connects to a HTTP/2 server with `allowHTTP1: true` set but doesn't handle the HTTP/1 request.

The examples are based on the [Node documentation example code](https://nodejs.org/api/http2.html#http2_server_side_example).

### HTTP/1 and /2 Mixed Server

```
const http2 = require('http2')
const fs = require('fs')

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('server-key.pem'), 
  cert: fs.readFileSync('server-crt.pem'), 
  //ca: fs.readFileSync('ca-crt.pem'), 
  allowHTTP1: true,
}

var server = http2.createSecureServer(options, (req, res) => {
  // detects if it is a HTTPS request or HTTP/2
  const { socket: { alpnProtocol } } = (req.httpVersion === '2.0')
    ? req.stream.session 
    : req

  res.writeHead(200, { 'content-type': 'application/json' })
  res.end(JSON.stringify({
    alpnProtocol,
    httpVersion: req.httpVersion
  }))
})

server.listen(8443)
```

### HTTP/2 Client

```
const http2 = require('http2')
const fs = require('fs')

const client = http2.connect('https://localhost:8443', {
    ca: fs.readFileSync('ca-crt.pem'),
    rejectUnauthorized: true,
})
client.on('socketError', (err) => console.error(err))
client.on('error', (err) => console.error(err))

const req = client.request({ ':path': '/' })

req.on('response', (headers, flags) => {
  for (const name in headers) {
    console.log('Header: "%s" "%s"', name, headers[name])
  }
})

req.setEncoding('utf8')
let data = ''
req.on('data', chunk => data += chunk)
req.on('end', () => {
  console.log('Data:', data)
  client.destroy()
})
req.end()
```

Then running:

```
→ node http2_client.js 
(node:34542) ExperimentalWarning: The http2 module is an experimental API.
Header: ":status" "200"
Header: "content-type" "application/json"
Header: "date" "Sat, 02 Dec 2017 23:27:21 GMT"
Data: {"alpnProtocol":"h2","httpVersion":"2.0"}
```

### HTTP/1 Client

```
const https = require('https')
const fs = require('fs')

var options = {
  method: 'GET',
  hostname: 'localhost',
  port: '8443',
  path: '/',
  protocol: 'https:',
  ca: fs.readFileSync('ca-crt.pem'),
  rejectUnauthorized: true,
  //agent: false
}

var req = https.request(options, function(res){
  var body = ''
  res.setEncoding('utf8')
  res.on('data', data => body += data)
  res.on('end', ()=> console.log('Body:', body))
})

req.on('response', response => {
  for (const name in response.headers) {
    console.log('Header: "%s" "%s"', name, response.headers[name])
  }
})

req.end()
```

Then running

```
→ node http1_client.js 
Header: "content-type" "application/json"
Header: "date" "Sat, 02 Dec 2017 23:27:08 GMT"
Header: "connection" "close"
Header: "transfer-encoding" "chunked"
Body: {"alpnProtocol":false,"httpVersion":"1.1"}
```

### HTTP/2 Server

Using the plain HTTP/2 Server will work with the `http2_client` but will "hang" for a `http1_client`. The TLS connection from a HTTP/1 client will be closed when you remove `allowHTTP1: true`.

```
const http2 = require('http2')
const fs = require('fs')

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('server-key.pem'), 
  cert: fs.readFileSync('server-crt.pem'), 
  ca: fs.readFileSync('ca-crt.pem'), 
  allowHTTP1: true,
}

var server = http2.createSecureServer(options)
server.on('error', error => console.log(error))
server.on('connect', conn => console.log('connect', conn))
server.on('socketError', error => console.log('socketError', error))
server.on('frameError', error => console.log('frameError', error))
server.on('remoteSettings', settings => console.log('remote settings', settings))

server.on('stream', (stream, headers) => {
  console.log('stream', headers)
  stream.respond({
    'content-type': 'application/html',
    ':status': 200
  })
  console.log(stream.session)
  stream.end(JSON.stringify({
    alpnProtocol: stream.session.socket.alpnProtocol,
    httpVersion: "2"
  }))
})

server.listen(8443)
```

### Certs

With the extended intermediate certificate setup detailed in the gist, the complete certificate chain for the CA needs to be supplied to the clients.

```
cat ca/x/certs/x.public.pem > caxy.pem
cat ca/y/certs/y.public.pem >> caxy.pem
```

Then in the clients use this `ca` in the options.

```
{ 
  ca: fs.readFileSync('caxy.pem'),
}
```

These examples were run withe the following simple CA setup from [this circle.com article](https://engineering.circle.com/https-authorized-certs-with-node-js-315e548354a2):

> To simplify the configuration, let’s grab the following CA
>   configuration file.
>
> ```
> wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/anders94/https-authorized-clients/master/keys/ca.cnf
> ```
>
> Next, we’ll create a new certificate authority using this
>   configuration.
>
> ```
> openssl req -new -x509 \
>   -days 9999 \
>   -config ca.cnf \
>   -keyout ca-key.pem \
>   -out ca-crt.pem
> ```
>
> Now that we have our certificate authority in ca-key.pem and
>   ca-crt.pem, let’s generate a private key for the server.
>
> ```
> openssl genrsa \
>   -out server-key.pem \
>   4096
> ```
>
> Our next move is to generate a certificate signing request. Again to
>   simplify configuration, let’s use server.cnf as a configuration
>   shortcut.
>
> ```
> wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/anders94/https-authorized-clients/master/keys/server.cnf
> ```
>
> Now we’ll generate the certificate signing request.
>
> ```
> openssl req -new \
>   -config server.cnf \
>   -key server-key.pem \
>   -out server-csr.pem
> ```
>
> Now let’s sign the request.
>
> ```
> openssl x509 -req -extfile server.cnf \
>   -days 999 \
>   -passin "pass:password" \
>   -in server-csr.pem \
>   -CA ca-crt.pem \
>   -CAkey ca-key.pem \
>   -CAcreateserial \
>   -out server-crt.pem
> ```

Comment: Here are the details of my setup. Not sure if this is exactly what I used but close. https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/eedfdc9bf554b36279868b335c96d2e2

Comment: Also wondering why it works in the browser but not in node.js. I can't get it to actually get to the first part of the server request code, the request never goes through.

Comment: Modern browsers include http2 support

Comment: A http2 client works in nodejs. Or do you mean you can't get a request to go though in the above mixed http1/2 server example?

Comment: It works, I have no idea what I did differently. Thank you.

Comment: It gives the error I was getting if I remove `rejectUnauthorized: false`. `Uncaught Error: unable to verify the first certificate`. I only want to allow for authorized stuff. Again, the browser works even with `rejectUnauthorized: true`.

Comment: I also get socket hang up when I try without rejectUnauthorized: false. Not sure.

Comment: To remove `rejectUnauthorized` the clients require the CA certs, updated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160363/discussion-between-lance-pollard-and-matt).